# Capturar e filtrar resultado

Tags: php

Possuo uma string

```
<div></div>
[........]
<p>Ola meu nome é pseudomatica (sou normal), etc. Meu nome é assim pq sim</p>
<p></p>
[........]
```

Como faço para o conteudo da primeira `<p>`, ou seja a `Ola meu nome é pseudomatica (sou normal), etc. Meu nome é assim pq sim`

e desse conteúdo remover tudo que tiver entre parênteses (inclusive os parenteses) e por ultimo pegar o texto que antecede o primeiro ponto final, ficando o resultado final:

`Ola meu nome é pseudomatica, etc.`

Answer (score 6):

## Apanhar o valor do primeiro `<p/>`

Uma maneira prática é pegar nesse HTML e gerar um DOM do mesmo através da classe de PHP [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$html = '<div></div>
<p>Ola meu nome é pseudomatica (sou normal), etc. Meu nome é assim pq sim</p>
<p></p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// de todos os p, fica com o texto do primeiro
$p = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue; 

// divide o texto por '.' e fica com a primeira parte
$texto = explode(".", $p)[0];
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/33Po0t):

```
var_dump(explode(".", $p)[0]); // string(48) "Ola meu nome é pseudomatica (sou normal), etc"
```

## Retirar parênteses e seu conteúdo

Depois, podes fazer uso de uma expressão regular para retirares o texto entre parênteses incluindo os parênteses:

```
$texto = explode(".", $p)[0];
$textoFinal = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","", $texto);
```

Exemplo no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/rfgjnT):

```
var_dump(preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","", $texto));  // Ola meu nome é pseudomatica , etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Confesso que se não fosse o exemplo de como a string deveria ficar depois de capturada e limpa teria sido quase impossível de responder.

E esses "*placeholders*" [....] dificultaram ainda mais.

Bom, primeiro você tem que localizar todo o texto, qualquer que seja **até** um ponto final:

```
preg_match( '/<p>(.*?\.).*?<\/p>/', $string, $text );
```

Se encontrar esse parágrafo, a variável **$text** terá dois índices: No primeiro tudo o que foi casado e no segundo só o que estiver dentro dos `<p>`.

Capturado, você limpa:

```
preg_replace( '/\s\(.*?\)/', '', $text[ 1 ] );
```

A limpeza é feita localizando um espaço, seguido de um abre-parêntese, com qualquer coisa dentro e um fecha-parêntese.

Localizado esse fragmento, ele é todo removido e astring resultante:

```
Ola meu nome é pseudomatica, etc.
```

O código completo:

```
$string = '<div></div>
[........]
<p>Ola meu nome é pseudomatica (sou normal), etc. Meu nome é assim pq sim</p>
<p></p>
[........]';

if( preg_match( '/<p>(.*?\.).*?<\/p>/', $string, $text ) != 0 ) {

    echo preg_replace( '/\s\(.*?\)/', '', $text[ 1 ] );
}
```

Comment: e como posso obter uma div apartir da class que ela possui?

Comment: Isso já seria outra pergunta, mas pra não te deixar na mão, sugiro que leia [esse guia](aurelio.net/regex/guia). É simplesmente o melhor material sobre Expressões Regulares disponível em português.