# Como retornar uma parte de uma string (um elemento html) em php?

Tags: php, jquery, json, dom

Estou fazendo um "recurso técnico" para poder retornar o status dos servidores da SEFAZ de emissão de notas fiscais utilizando PHP. Para isso, eu tenho até o momento o código abaixo:

```
function get_content($URL){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$d = get_content('http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/disponibilidade.aspx');
echo $d;
```

Este código me retorna a página que a receita disponibiliza sem precisar de certificado digital para ver o status dos servidores.

Preciso saber como eu posso fazer para pegar somente um elemento HTML existente dentro da variável `$d` (o elemento é o `table.tabelaListagemDados`) e a partir dos valores dele posso fazer tratamentos.

Sei que eu consigo fazer o tratamento dessa informação utilizando javascript (puro, com AngularJS ou com jQuery) mas se existir algum método através do PHP é melhor pois assim eu consigo retornar somente um JSON e não uma página inteira.

Alguém vê uma solução sobre como eu posso fazer para pegar somente esse elemento dentro da página?

Comment: Estes links devem ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44694/capturar-e-filtrar-resultado, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/78621/como-extrair-dados-espec%C3%ADficos-de-um-arquivo-html-com-php

Comment: Com certeza @bfavaretto! Eles me ajudaram bastante! deu trabalho mas ta lá a biblioteca (se precisar o link ta na pergunta)

Answer (score 3):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
$data = get_content('http://www.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/portal/disponibilidade.aspx');
$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($data);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$rows = $tables->item(1)->getElementsByTagName('tr');

foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        print_r($cols);
}
```

Comment: tks @Samir Braga

Comment: kra isso me ajuda sim mas não posso pegar somente os elementos tr dentro da table... lá na sefaz eles enfiaram uma tag caption que contém a hora do resultado de consulta, isso é interessante também

Comment: assim que tiver tudo certinho, retornando como JSON eu posto na wiki do stack

Answer (score 1):

Fala galera, consegui resolver meu problema. Abaixo está o script que pega a página que mostra a disponibilidade dos webservices de envio de nota fiscal eletronica e transforma o conteúdo em um json.

**https://github.com/leandroluk/wsDisponibilidadeSefaz/**

Ta ai pra quem quiser usar, fiquem a vontade, mas por favor deixem os créditos rs.